# [[ operator fails with error "conditional binary operator expected"

Tags: linux, shell, unix, expression

Linux bash script fails for the following line. Error message as given. I know i can simply use `if [ -f file1.txt ]` but curious to know what needs to be fixed to make this working.

```
[[ -f file1.txt && (( mv file1.txt file1_old.txt )) ]]
```

> conditional binary operator expected
>   expected `)'

Comment: Apologies if this is already answered. I checked couple of posts with the same error. But couldn't fix this code based on that. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mv` command shouldn't be inside the conditional expression, it's a command that you want to execute depending on the result of the condition. It should be

```
[[ -f file1.txt ]] && mv file1.txt file1_old.txt
```

Also, don't put it inside double parentheses, that's for arithmetic expressions, not commands.

Comment: @zee I'm not a big believer in that kind of code. If you want an `else` statement, use `if`.

Comment: I don't think that bash will treat those double parentheses as an arithmetic expression. I think it will treat them just as double nested parentheses pairs used to group conditional expressions. `[[ (( a = a )) ]]` is similar to `[[ a = a ]]`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @mosvy You're correct. My point was that it's never correct to put double parentheses around a command. You can use single parentheses to run it in a subshell.